# Convert String to Array in Golang

Tags: go

I have a string that is from an text file. I was able to get it via 'io/ioutil' it contains the following text:

```
"[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0,3 ]]"
```

How do I convert this string to an array that I can use in a for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing explicit arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333562/parsing-explicit-arrays/40333763#40333763).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Go so I have no explicit understanding on how to convert things.

Comment: consider following the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/) which walks through most of the language fairly quickly, including the basics such as how to work with arrays and strings.

Answer (score 3):

Go is a strictly typed language so there isn't something like an eval statement that turns data into code directly.  In this case that you asked about, seeing that your list of lists is in a format compatible with the JSON format, I thought of using the JSON package to do the parsing.  So it takes only three lines of code, defining the type of data that is expected, creating the decoder from the string, and applying the decoder to the data type.  The fact that Go is strictly typed but supports reflection (which you won't see in this code) is what took me a little time to get used to.  Reflection is what makes the third line possible and why the first line defines the variable as a list of lists ([][]int).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// Prints:
// <nil> [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3]]
// 0 0 0
// 0 1 1
// 1 0 0
// 1 1 2
// 2 0 0
// 2 1 3

func main() {
    jsonstring := "[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0,3 ]]"
    var listoflists [][]int
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonstring))
    err := dec.Decode(&listoflists)
    fmt.Println(err, listoflists)
    for i, list := range listoflists {
        for j, value := range list {
            fmt.Println(i, j, value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: icza's link to a similar question has a much more thorough answer giving more details about the json package.  Maybe view this as a simple primer.  I'll also mention here that there have been questions about how to parse a string when it was not in JSON format and sometimes the easiest Go program to handle it turned out to be writing a parser for the string that just created a new string from it that was in JSON format and then letting the json package do the heavy lifting.